# My attempt to implement linear memristor

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current, maxwell-equations

Memristor, which makes relationship between charge and flux, has not been discovered, according to Wikipedia. So I tried to implement it, here linear.

As it both stores charges and induces magnetic flux, I thought it as some chimera of capacitor and inductor, and came up with the structure below:

[image]

Though I can't tell it actually works, because of the following reasons:

1. How should the wires be modeled like? They cannot be thickless lines, as it would violate Kirchhoff's current law.
2. What will the charges distributed like? Will they be evenly distributed? Will they also be distributed in the vertical wires?
3. Until where will the magnetic field be? Will it be just like above, so I could calculate flux by integrating within rectangle?
4. How should be Maxwell's equations applied? They tell about electric fields and magnetic fields, not charges and fluxes.

Regardless of whether it is actually a memristor, I'd like to solve the system. Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that memristors are not hypothetical since 2008, but are actually being built: e.g. https://phys.org/news/2018-01-team-deep-memristors.html

Comment: @AndersSandberg That seems nonlinear, and I aim to implement memristor as a fully passive component.