# Proof that true passive linear memristors don't exist

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electric-current, charge

This is a sequel to the following (now irrelevent) question: [My attempt to implement linear memristor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399277/186081)

Assume the "conceptual symmetry" of the fundamental passive circuit elements holds: [image: Conceptual symmetry]

Then let's turn to the microscopic view. That is, instead of $v$, $i$, $q$, and $\Phi$, we take $\vec{E}$, $\vec{J}$, $\rho$, and $\vec{B}$ as the variables in relation.

Now ,note that, for each "known" elements, the other than the related variables are assumed to be zero. Those are:

1. For a resistor, since it consists of ohmic material, $\rho$ is inherently zero. Also, $\vec{B}$ is also assumed to be zero, so there are no eddy current, and then the Ohm's law, $\sigma \vec{E} = \vec{J}$, is satisfied.
2. For a capacitor, in ideal condition, the system is assumed to in a steady state and the plates are assumed to be infinite. That is, $\vec{J}$ is assumed to be zero inside the plates (and inside the dielectric, of course). Consequently, $\nabla \times \vec{B} = \vec{0}$, meaning that $\vec{B}$ is uniform. Also, since $\vec{E}$ is uniform by spatial symmetry, $\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = \vec{0}$, meaning that $\vec{B}$ is also constant. For simplicity, $\vec{B}$ is also assumed to be zero.
3. For an inductor, in ideal condition, it is assumed that $\vec{J}$ is the only variable that induces $\vec{B}$. That is, $\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} = \vec{0}$ and $\nabla \times \vec{E} = \vec{0}$, consequently $\vec{E}$ is constantly uniform, or for simplicity, zero. Also, it is assumed that $\rho$ inside the coil and the core is zero throughout.

Then what about a memristor? If the symmetry really holds, it must be assumed that $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{J}$ are zero throughout. But then, by Gauss' law:
$$
\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0} = \nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \nabla \cdot \vec{0} = 0
$$
meaning that $\rho$ is zero throughout, and by Faraday's law:
$$
-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = \nabla \times \vec{E} = \nabla \times \vec{0} = \vec{0}
$$
meaning that $\vec{B}$ is constant, and by Ampere-Maxwell law:
$$
\nabla \times \vec{B} = \mu_0 (\vec{J} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}) = \vec{0}
$$
meaning that $\vec{B}$ is uniform.

So in summary, assuming $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{J}$ to be zero implies that $\rho$ and $\vec{B}$ are also trivial, breaking the assumed "conceptual symmetry". This is a contradiction.

Is this "proof" valid? So, does that mean linear memristors really don't exist?

Comment: Has the following work been shown to be flawed or is it nonlinear?  https://www.nature.com/articles/nature06932

Comment: @honeste_vivere It appears to be nonlinear. Meanwhile, as I aimed to implement memristors by classical theories of electromagnetism (i.e. no semiconductors), I cannot tell whether it is implementable by modern theories of electromagnetism (e.g. QED).